# Android JUnit testing Application class

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium, instrumentation

I am trying to setup JUnit test cases for an app I am developing currently. The main problem I am facing is that I am not able to get access of an object which I am storing in my Application class.
I am extending the AndroidTestCase class for writing test cases.

I tried getting access to that object(say myData) by

```
Myapp app = (Myapp) getContext()
                .getApplicationContext();
String myData=app.getData();
```

But this is throwing null pointer exception at app.getData();
how can i access this object at run time?

Answer (score 2):

Please, show more code, class where `extends AndroidTestCase`, class where `extends TestSuite`

Also, you may forget add to **AndroidManifest**:

```
...

  <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="YOUR_PACKAGE"/>

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="YOUR_APPLICATION_CLASS">

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have not added android:name="" property in the  application tag in Manifest of test application. How should I add? What should be the class name? Say my target app has applciation class 'MyApp', then what should be added in the manifest of test app

Comment: i think **android:name="MyApp"** if no under packages, try use suggestions hotkey for your IDE, like ctrl + space for Intellij Idea

Comment: @artemiygrn How to Unit test/ instatiate Custom Application class.